# For Python2 to Python3 code conversion, Which version of Python & Django best suited?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2to3

Currently I am working in big firm where we need to convert python2 old big Django project into python3 version so I have done lots of research related but still not able to find any perfect answer related to which version of Python and Django best suited for conversion.

Currently I am using Python : 2.7.16 & Django : 1.9.13 in my old version.

Anyone can suggest me best suited version of Python & Django for above old version for python2 to python3 conversion.

Comment: The current version of python3 is Python 3.8, and the latest version of Django is Django 3.0. [Django's website recommends the latest version of python 3](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/), which is 3.8. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to accelerate both python and django to their most recent versions?

Comment: Anecdotally, I only realized a few days ago that the Django-based website that I've been maintaining for a few years now actually runs on the server it's hosted on using python2.7, whereas I've been running it locally using python3.7. The only difference I found was when I tried to use f-strings somewhere for the first time and the webserver's version crashed; otherwise it's been running exactly as expected (exactly the same) locally and remotely, for the purposes of testing and feature addition. My entirely anecdotal conclusion is that Django is generally compatible with most things.

Comment: for latest version, I have found that some people don't recommend because in latest version if have any problem related new updates then it will be difficult to find solution sometimes so in current project I do not want make such kind of risk & also for testing purspose , I have started to convert my project  to python 3.7.3 latest version with latest django and already found 30 kind of issues.

Comment: It should be noted - this question came up in a review audit for me. "Is there any document or reference" is very clearly off-topic (asking for an off-site resource). However, I believe the question could be edited such that it could better lead into the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought I'd add a bit to the *strategy* advocated by Wim's answer - get the appropriate version of Django working on both 2.7 and 3.x first - and outline some *tactics* that worked for me.

#### Python 2.7 is your escape pod, until you pull the trigger on 3.x

- your tests should run on both
- don't use any 3.x specific features, like f-strings
- first Python 3.x, then only later Django 2.x which doesn't run on 2.7
- start early, don't over analyze, but avoid the big bang approach

  - file by file at first.
  - start with the lowest level code, like utility libraries, that you have test suites for.
  - if possible, try to gradually merge your changes to the 2.7 production branches and keep your 3.x porting code up to date with prod changes.

#### Which minor version of Django to start with?

My criteria here is that Django migrations can be fairly involved (and actually require more thinking than 2=>3 work).  So I would move to the latest and greatest 1.11 that way you're already providing some value to your 2.7 users.  There's probably a good number of pre-2.x compatibility shims on 1.11 **and** you'll be getting its 2.x deprecation warnings.

#### Which minor version of Python 3.x to start with?

Best to consider all angles, such as the availability of your 3rd party libs, support from your CI/devops suite and availability on your chosen server OS images.  You could always install 3.8 and try a pip install of your requirements.txt by itself, for example.

#### Leverage **git** (or whatever scm you use) and **virtualenv**.

- separate `requirement.txt` files, but...
- if you have a file-based, git repo, you can point each venv at the **same codeline** with a `pip install -e <your directory>`.  that means that, in 2 different terminals you can run 2.7 and 3.x against the same unittest(s).
- you could even run 2.7 and 3.x Django servers side-by-side on different ports and point say Firefox and Chrome at them.
- commit often (on the porting branch at least) and learn about **git bisect**.

#### make use of **2to3**

Yes, it will break 2.7 code and Django if you let it.  So...

- run it in preview mode or against a single file.  see what it breaks but also see what it did right.
- throttle it to only certain conversions that **don't** break 2.7 or Django.  `print x`=> `print (x)` and `except(Exception) as e` are 2 no-brainers.

This is what my throttled command looked like:

```
2to3 $tgt -w -f except -f raise -f next -f funcattrs -f print
```

- run it file-by-file until you are really confident.

#### use **sed** or **awk** rather than your editor for bulk conversions.

The advantage is that, as you become more aware of your apps' specifics concerns, you can build a suite of changes that can be run on either 1 file or many files and do most of the work without breaking 2.7 or Django.  Apply this **after** your suitably-throttled **2to3** pass.  That leaves you with residual cleanups in your editor and getting your tests to pass.

#### (optional) start running **black** on 2.7 code.

black which is a code formatter, uses Python 3 ASTs to run its analysis.  It doesn't  try to run the code, but it will flag syntax errors that prevent it from getting to the AST stage.  You will have to work some pip install global magic to get there though and you have to buy into black's usefulness.

#### Other people have done it - learn from them.

Listening to [#155 Practical steps for moving to Python 3](https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/talk-python-to-me/155-practical-steps-for-Te_hoKRQvV6/) should give you some ideas of the work.  Look at the show links for it.  They love to talk up the Instagram(?) move which involved a gradual adjustment of running 2.7 code to 3.x syntax on a common codebase, and on the same git branch, until pull-the-trigger day.

See also [The Conservative Python 3 Porting Guide](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

and [Instagram Makes a Smooth Move to Python 3](https://thenewstack.io/instagram-makes-smooth-move-python-3/) - The New Stack

### Conclusion

Your time to Django 1.11 EOL (April 2020) is rather short, so if you have 2+ dev resources to throw at it, I'd consider doing the following in parallel:

- DEV#1: start out on a Django 1.11 bump (the theory being that Django 1.11 is probably best positioned as a jump off point to Django 2.x), using 2.7.
- DEV#2: get started on Python 3.6/3.7 of your non-Django utility code.  Since the code is 2.7 compatible at this point, merge it into #1 as you go.

See how both tasks proceed, assess what the Django related project risk is and what the Python 3 pain looks like.  You're already missing the Python 2.7 EOL, but an obsolete web framework is probably more dangerous than legacy Python 2.7, at least for a few months.  So I wouldn't wait too long to start migrating off Django 1.9 and your work doing so won't be wasted.  As you see the progress, you'll start seeing the project risks better.

Your initial 2to3 progress will be slow, but the tooling and guidance is good enough that you'll quickly pick up speed so don't overthink it before starting to gather experience.  The Django side depends on **your** exposure to breaking changes in the framework which is why I think it's best to start early.

#### P.S. (controversial/personal opinion) I didn't use **six** or other canned 2-to-3 bridge libraries much.

It's **not** because I don't trust it - it's brilliant for 3rd party libs - but rather that I didn't want to add a complex permanent dependency (and I was too lazy to read its doc).  I'd been writing 2.7 code in 3.x compatible syntax for a long time so I didn't really feel the need to use them.  **Your mileage may vary and don't set out on this path if it seems like a lot of work**.

Instead, I created a **py223.py** (57 LOC incl. comments) with this type of content, most of which is concerned with workarounds for deprecations and name changes in the standard library.

```
try:
    basestring_ = basestring
except (NameError,) as e:
    basestring_ = str

try:
    cmp_ = cmp
except (NameError,) as e:
    # from http://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html
    def cmp_(x, y):
        """
        Replacement for built-in function cmp that was removed in Python 3
        """
        return (x > y) - (x < y)
```

Then import from that py223 to work around those specific concerns.  Later on I will just ditch the import and move those weird `isinstance(x, basestr_)` to `isinstance(x, str)` but I know in advance there is little to worry about.

Comment: Good advice. Just one note, Django itself already uses `six` for the compatibility layer, so if you want to use it in a Django project during the transition, then this is not "adding a complex permanent dependency".

Comment: @wim.  I agree with you re. six, but it depends on the viewpoint.  I already noted that it comes with 3rd party libs, so it doesn't "cost" in terms of requirements and overall dependencies.  however I - maybe wrongly - considered it a big *black box/wart* in the middle of **my** code.  if all you're doing is things like testing instance string/unicode/basestring and if you know how to do that yourself, then you know exactly how to back your shims out when they're not needed anymore.  I'll move that to the end, though.

Comment: It's `pip install -e ...` (with a lower case `-e`), right?

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to first upgrade to `Django==1.11.26`, which is the most recent version of Django that is supporting both Python 2 and Python 3.  Stay on your current version of Python 2.7 for now.

Read carefully the release notes for 1.10.x and 1.11.x, checking for deprecations and fixing anything that stopped working from your 1.9.x code. Things WILL break. Django moves fast. For a large Django project, there may be many code changes required, and if you're using a lot of 3rd-party plugins or libraries you may have to juggle their versions around. Some of your 3rd-party dependencies will probably have been abandoned entirely, so you have to find replacements or remove the features.

To find the release notes for each version upgrade, just google "What's new in Django ".  The hits will meticulously document all the deprecations and changes:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.10/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.11/

Once the webapp appears to be working fine on Django 1.11, with all tests passing (you *do* have a test suite, right?) then you can do the Python 3 conversion, whilst keeping the Django version the same. Django 1.11 supports up to Python 3.7, so that would be a good version to target. Expect unicode all over the place, since the implicit conversions between bytes and text is gone now and many Python 2 webapps relied upon that.

Once the project appears to be working fine on Django 1.11 and Python 3.7, then you can think about upgrading to Django 3.0, following the same process as before - reading the release notes, making the necessary changes, running the test suite, and checking out the webapp in a dev server manually.

Comment: Definitely the way to go.  Get your test code to run on both 2.7 and 3.x.  You can have 2 different virtualenvs pointing at the same git repo with `pip install -E`.  Once the unit tests are running, start test usage of Django-on-3x and again keep code working in 2 and 3.  With some careful coding and being careful not to burn your 2.7 bridges - no f strings for example - the switchover will be very anticlimactic.  Once 3.x is entirely stable, start using 3.x only code.  The advantage is that the production 2.7 is always in step until switch.

Answer (score 2):

I would upgrade to py3 first. You'll need to look at `setup.py` in the Django repo on the stable/1.9.x branch (https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/setup.py) to figure out that the py3 versions supported are 3.4 (dead) and 3.5.

Once you're on py3.5 and Django 1.9 you can upgrade one at a time until you get to the version you want to end at. E.g. Django 1.11 supports py3.5 and py3.7, so

```
py27/dj19 -> py35/dj19 -> py35/dj1.11 -> py37/dj1.11 ... -> py37/dj2.2
```

dj2.2 is the first version supporting py3.8, but I would probably stop at py37/dj2.2 if you're working in a normally conservative environment.

If you have other packages you'll need to find version combinations that will work together on each step. Having a plan is key, and upgrading only one component at a time will usually end up saving you time.

The future library (https://python-future.org/) will help you with many icky situations while you need code to run on both py27 and 3.x. six is great too. I would avoid rolling your own compatibility layer (why reinvent the wheel?)

If at all possible, try to get your unit test coverage up to 75-85% before starting, and definitely set up automatic testing on both "from" and "to" versions for each upgrade step. Make sure you read and fix all warnings from Django before upgrading to the next version -- Django cares very little about backward compatibility, so I would normally suggest hitting every minor version on the upgrade path (or at least make sure you read the "backwards incompatibilities" and deprecation lists for each minor version).

Good luck (we're upgrading a 300+Kloc code base from py27/dj1.7 right now, so I feel your pain ;-)

Comment: +1 on test coverage.  That’s a key metric here, whatever approach one ends up taking.  It really helps when experimenting with pervasive code changes and I am saying this as someone who is **not** at all a TDD Red/Green test aficionado.  Figure out a way to baseline your 2.7 outcomes and upgrading becomes a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

I have same kind of issue with my project and I have tried python 3.7.5 with Django version 2.2.7.

You should not go with python latest version 3.8 or Django latest version 3.0 because you there may have been chances that for any kind of bug you may not able to get proper solution for latest versions.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score -2):

You should try to shoot for the current versions. Python 3.8 and Django 3.0.The Six library will help with some convention changes. Either way you are going to have to do some refactoring so you might as well make it current.

Comment: Have you ever done a Django upgrade? This is just wishful thinking. Going directly to Python 3.8 and Django 3.0 from 2.7 / 1.9 will be virtually impossible.  Even upgrading minor versions like Django 1.9 to 1.10 can be a difficult process, with many code changes needed.

Comment: Yes I have, granted I had the luxury and time approval to do a complete refactor and bring the application current. Again application size, logic  and time constraints are a huge issue for most guys but they never mentioned application size or time constraint, so I recommended my opinion of "best solution" or "wishful thinking" ;)

Comment: additionally if you have to worry about things Ansible and running on a LTS Ubuntu as well, you’ll find even 3.7 support is lacking on Ubuntu 18.04.  Security podcasts I listen advise letting 3.8 settle a bit till a point release or 2.  -1 for unnecessary risk.

Comment: For Python sec, https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/talk-python-to-me/168-10-python-security-holes-ObaYMCAJhTe/    But I think the beware-of-3.8-for-a-while one is more recent.  *Risky Business* is a good and entertaining security podcast, esp if you follow international relations.  Apologies for downvote, but yeah, what worked in your case might tarpit someone else in a different context.  For 2 to 3 conversion see  https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/talk-python-to-me/155-practical-steps-for-Te_hoKRQvV6/

Comment: I understand, we can only make each other better with creative criticism. Thank you for the podcast recommendations!